# Type inference lost when checking Mongoose model existance

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I've run into a problem combining Typescript and Mongoose. I've defined a model:

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  some more props... 
});

export const UserModel = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

But due to live reload in my app I get a crash when a file changes and it tries to define the model again:

```bash
OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `User` model once compiled.
```

Reading answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73424777/12794481) it suggests we check if the model is already defined:

```js
export const UserModel = mongoose.models?.User || mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
```

While it kind of works, document type inference is now lost from model operations:

```js
const user = await UserModel.findOne(); // user has 'any' type
```

The issue seems to come from `mongoose.models["User"]` which can't know at static time what type it has. So the type needs to be inferred from `mongoose.model("User", userSchema)` but it is also only allowed to be executed once and this is where I'm stuck.

Comment: How did you do the live reload? How can we reproduce the issue?

Comment: In my case Im using the Remix framework but its not so much about how the reload is done but the problem lies in the fact that when you have a live reload that clears the import cache, a check `export const UserModel = mongoose.models?.User || mongoose.model("User", userSchema)` is necessary. But adding the check causes the loss of the typing.
So to reproduce, just set up the mongoose model as shown in any framework that uses live reload.